# html5 video tag not playing mp4 - IIS

Tags: html, iis, html5-video, mp4

The problem I am having is that I am unable to get mp4 videos to run via a video tag.

The server is IIS 7.5 on Win7 Ultimate.

The htm in the file is rather simple and vanilla:

```
<video width="360" height="240"  controls="controls" >
    <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

In "Internet Explorer" the tag renders a black box with a red cross.

In Firefox the tag renders as a grey box with a light-grey cross and the words "No video with supported format and MIME type found.".

I know what you're thinking - add the MIME type. I have done this two different ways with no success; first I tried adding the MIME type in IIS, and then I have tried adding via the web.config with

```
<staticContent>  
  <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
</staticContent>
```

Neither of these made a difference. I have also typed the .mp4 file directly into the address bad and both IE and firefox are able to play it. Furthermore I have gone to websites that have use 'video' tag in both IE and firefox and they play the videos just fine.

Can somebody please assist me in why this wont play, and what I can do to get it to play?

Thanks

Comment: More info - 

I have gone to this website - http://leanbackplayer.com/ This is simply a jquery UI wrapper on the video tag. The video on that page works fine in my FireFox. 

I have downloaded all three videos (.ogv, webm, mp4) and used the same tags as that website (changing location of videos), and added mime types AND IT DOESN'T WORK!??!

Comment: Besides trying to change the MIME type you should verify that the files are sent with that type. You can use the development tools of your browser or Fiddler.

Comment: did you have any luck with this issue? In my case, I can see MP4 and M4V video source in IE9 when I open the HTML page as a file from the hard disk. But when I try to access the page from my local IIS web server, all sources shows as black area with red cross. The same if I try to access the page from my site hosted on the web. - And, yes, I've added MIME types to my local server.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely check Chrome/Safari as suggested. Firefox doesn't support MP4 files through HTML5 video. You need a WEBM file or a fallback flash player to support Firefox (which I'm assuming Leanback does).

Overall it sounds like an issue with your version of IE9, and might be limited to your machine. Does the leanback player's video work in IE9 for you? Or the video on [videojs.com](http://videojs.com)? I've tested the latter myself in IE9 multiple times.

Otherwise there could be corruption in your mp4 file that IE9 can't support. I explained this more [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809093/html5-video-plays-in-chrome-but-not-ie9).

Comment: I think he mentioned in 1st comment that videos from leanbackplayer do not work in his IE9, so it should not be a matter of corrupted mp4 file.